# Drag & Drop row with parents and childs

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table when I integrate a tree table with `simple-tree-table`. With that I can work with parents and child row, collapse and expand.

Now I'm trying to drag & drop rows with jQuery sortable and I can drag rows well but I need to drag a parents along with their children too and now what happens is I can only drag the parent. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/simple-tree-table.html).

To sort the rows I have this code, if `tr` is a child the drop is not possible otherwise I can sort the row.

What I need is to detect if the parent has children and if it does then I have to drop parent and child. How can I do that?

```html
<table id="gama">
  <tr data-node-id="1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>text of 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-node-id="1.1" data-node-pid="1">
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>text of 1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-node-id="2">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>text of 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-node-id="2.1" data-node-pid="2">
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td>text of 2.1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$("#gama tbody tr.child").sortable({
  helper: fixHelperModified,
  stop: updateIndex,
  cursor: 'no-drop',
}).disableSelection();

$("tbody").sortable({
  distance: 5,
  delay: 100,
  opacity: 0.6,
  cursor: 'move'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to find elements with the attribute `data-node-pid` that start with the parent element's `data-node-id`.

For example, to find the children of the element with `data-node-id="1"`, you could do:

```
$("tr[data-node-pid^='1']")
```

which would return all the  nodes with `data-node-pid` starting with '1' (e.g. '1.1', '1.2.1', etc). If it's empty, the parent has no children.